# Sending batch readings from Photon via Pubnub for display in EON chart

Tags: javascript, charts, pubnub, photon

Using my Photon, I am recording 4000 sensor readings (stored in an array) for 1 second. I am then batching the readings into groups of 100 and sending this as a message to a website via PUBNUB.

The PUBNUB library for the photon is very fussy about the structure of the message, and crashes (red flashing) if the message is not 100% correct. The structure that works is [{"Time":"1456", "Value":"1"},{"Time":"1458", "Value":"2"}].

Here is the batching code:

```
void myReadings(int aData[], float aTime[], int nX)
{
    int x = 0;
    while (x <= nX) {
        String stringTemp = "[";
        for (int q= 0; q <= 100; q++)
        {
            if (x <= nX) {
                stringTemp += "{\"Time\":\"" + String(aTime[x]) + "\",\"Value\":\"" + String(aData[x]) + "\"}";
                if (q < 100 and x< nX)
                {
                    stringTemp += ",";
                }
                x += 1;
            }
        }

        stringTemp += "]";
        int strLen = stringTemp.length();
        char * msg = new char[strLen + 1];
        stringTemp.toCharArray(msg, strLen + 1);
        Serial.println(msg);
        TCPClient * client;
        client = PubNub.publish(channel, msg);
        client ->stop();
        Serial.println("Message sent");
        delay(1000);

    }
```

On the web side, I cannot get my Javascript to cycle through the array and plot Time vs Value point. I know the message is arriving, but I can't get anything plotted.

Please could you help with the Javascript that will cycle through the array and plot the points.

Here is the Javascript I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
        publish_key: 'XXXX',
        subscribe_key: 'YYY',
        error: function (error) { console.log('Error:', error) }
    });
    var GraphChannel = "AmpValue";
    var h = false;

    charttemp = eon.chart({
        pubnub: pubnub,
        channel: GraphChannel,
        limit: 5000,
        xType: 'custom',
        xId: 'Time',
        history: h,
        flow: false,
        generate: {
            bindto: "#charttemp",
            data: { colors: {}, type: "spline" },
            size: { height: 600, width: 1000 },
            transition: { duration: 100 },
            axis: { x: { label: "Time", show: false }, y: { label: "Amps", show: true } },
            grid: { x: { show: false }, y: { show: true } },
        },
        transform: function (m) {
            return { eon: { 'Time': m.Time, 'Value': m.Value } }
        }
    });

</script>
```

Do I need to modify the published message, or do I need to modify the Javascript to cycle through the array for plotting?

Comment: that actually looks right!  hmm....

Comment: Try using EON Builder - https://www.pubnub.com/developers/eon/chart/builder/ it has code at the bottom of the tool for copy/paste.  It may have extra hints.

Comment: `PUBNUB.publish({  channel: 'AmpValue', message:  {"eon": {"Me":98,"Nick":15,"Ritika":62,"Emily":16,"Sami":44,"_eonDatetime":1480398857433}} });`

 - sooo maybe something like this:

`transform: function(m) { return {eon: { 'Time' : m.Time, 'Value' : m.Value, _eonDatetime: +new Date }}; }`